# 2D Array declaration in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage, swift2

I have now the following code:

`var items: [[String, UIImage]] = [["String", UIImage(named: "image")]]`

That errors out with `expected ']' in array type`, `consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'`, `expected declaration`, `class ViewController has no initializers`.

When I code it like `var items: [[]] = [["String", UIImage(named: "image")]]`

That results in `Expected Element type`.

When I leave the `[[]]` out in the type annotation (`var items = ...`), it results in an error telling me `type of expression is ambiguous without more context`.

How would I do this? I want it to be an array, not a dictionary (string in the above example is not the key and the UIImage is not the value).

Comment: I think that you cannot make an array with multiple types, use a dictionary instead of an array

Comment: cant you make an array of type Any?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to store two values of differing type in an array. You can put them in a tuple and then add them to the array, like so:

```
var items: [(String, UIImage)] = [("String", UIImage(named: "image")!)]
```

Answer (score -1):

For a two-dimensional array, just specify a type.

```
var items: [[AnyObject?]] = [["String", UIImage(named: "image")]]
```